# Amazon Web Services CodeDeploy HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS Error

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, deployment

I keep getting the following error when trying to deploy to AWS CodeDeploy.

> The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)

I've been doing a bunch of research and according to [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ec2-instances.html#troubleshooting-deploy-failures) it says the following commands will display the log file for CodeDeploy.

```
less /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log
```

Problem is that file is completely empty even after a failed deployment. Any ideas on how to fix this? Or where to go to find a more specific error to debug? Currently I can't even find a reason except for the reason above.

I have also tried following the steps at [this link](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/TxG2NAUYCGR638/View-AWS-CodeDeploy-logs-in-Amazon-CloudWatch-console) and it doesn't even show up in CloudWatch.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?